# Unable to use the Nearby API because Android package name

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to use the Nearby API on an Android Application, but it seems i have a problem with the package name. 
I'd done the following things. 
1. Create the application in the Google Developers Console and enable the Nearby API. 
2. I set the SHA-1 key in the Google's Console and get an API key for my application. 
3. The package name registered in the Console it's the same i have in the AndroidManifest.xml

I can´t find the problem. Actually I download a Google´s Nearby example and   set it up on my Console Application (changing the corresponding package name for this:

> com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.samples.nearbydevices

) and it works fine.

Why it´s this happening?

Any idea could be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you download the sample from google github, you should match the `package name` of that project unless you have changed it

Comment: I created a new project and registered the my package name in the google's console but it's not working, that's my problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Double check that the SHA1 FP match the one in the apk?

   ```
   $ keytool ­list ­printcert ­jarfile {my_app}.apk | grep SHA1
   SHA1: D8:AA:43:97:59:EE:C5:95:26:6A:07:EE:1C:37:8E:F4:F0:C8:05:C8
   ```
2. Make sure the api key is specified under the <application> element in the manifest

   ```
   <manifest   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="SPECIFY_YOUR_PACKAGE_HERE" >>     
   <application ...>
   <meta­data
    android:name="com.google.android.nearby.messages.API_KEY"
      android:value="SPECIFY_APPLICATION_API_KEY_HERE" />
   ```

If the above still don't work, what is the error you are getting?